# Join tables in two levels of subqueries in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I'm writing a query to find the furthest point to a location. My query is as below:

```
select sighting_ID, SQRT( POWER((28+latitude),2) + POWER((longitude-151),2)) AS distance
FROM sightings 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT sighting_id 
    FROM sightings 
    WHERE SQRT( POWER((28+latitude),2) + POWER((longitude-151),2)) < 
        (SELECT SQRT( POWER((28+latitude),2) + POWER((longitude-151),2))
         FROM sightings s1 join sightings s2
         WHERE s1.sighting_ID = s2.sighting_ID));
```

But an error occurs saying

> ERROR at line 'where s1.sighting_ID = s2.sighting_ID' : ORA-00905:
>   missing keyword'

I don't what I'm doing wrong.

---

The previous problem is solved. Here is my new query.

```
    select sighting_ID, SQRT( POWER((28+latitude),2) + POWER((longitude-151),2)) AS distance
from sightings 
WHERE NOT exists
(SELECT sighting_id 
    FROM sightings 
    WHERE SQRT( POWER((28+latitude),2) + POWER((longitude-151),2)) < 
( SELECT SQRT( POWER((28+s1.latitude),2) + POWER((s1.longitude-151),2))
    FROM sightings s1 join sightings s2
    ON s1.sighting_ID = s2.sighting_ID
    ));
```

But it says the very last select return more than one row. I understand what does this error massage mean. But how can I let the query to compare (<) every tuple returned by the last selection each by each?

Comment: I don't understand your query.  Why do you have hard-coded coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You use `ON` for `JOIN` not `WHERE`

```
   FROM sightings s1 
   join sightings s2
     ON s1.sighting_ID = s2.sighting_ID    
   ));
```